# Microsoft Graph - selfActivate requires MFA

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to trigger the PIM [selfActivate endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/privilegedrole_selfactivate) in my code. I'm able to query other endpoints (e.g. for the user's assigned roles), but when I issue the POST for selfActivate I receive a `401: Elevation requires Multi-Factor Authentication` error. How does one trigger an MFA challenge inline with MSAL to handle this response? I thought maybe I could pass along `&amr_values=mfa` in the query parameters, but when I do so I receive an error that the query is not currently supported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736832/azure-privileged-identity-selfactive-doesnt-work

Comment: Are you using MSAL.NET? In which case you might want to have a look at https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Adal-to-Msal#handling-claim-challenge-exceptions

Comment: @Jean-MarcPrieur I'm indeed using MSAL... but I do not get an auth exception from the AAD V2 endpoint. The exception is returned within the Graph response, not from Azure AD. If I try adding `claims={amr_values=mfa}` in the extraQueryParameters I still receive the same response. Example response follows... `{ "error": { "code": "UnknownError", "message": "Elevation requires Multi-Factor Authentication.", "innerError": { "request-id": "23371eb3-9afd-4fb6-b25b-d3394608a038", "date": "2018-03-15T12:29:11" } } }`

Answer (score -1):

There is an issue right now with MSGraph PIM api's that it won't work if your role requires MFA. This should be fixed soon and I will post back once its working.

Comment: I can confirm this still is not working, and not working via the create privilegedRoleAssignmentRequest API either. It doesn't work even when I am using a token with an MFA claim.